# Реализация функции int putchar(char c)

Tags: c

Хотелось бы посмотреть на реализацию `int putchar(char)`, но никак не могу найти её. Буду благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Где-то тут http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio должна быть (если не определена как макрос в stdio.h или подключаемых в него др. .h файлах)

Comment: Спасибо, поищу! но есть у меня ощущение , что она действительно определена макросом

Comment: Реализации могут быть разные. Например *glibc* гуглится [тут](https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.25/putchar_8c_source.html).

Comment: Судя по `/usr/include/stdio.h:extern int putchar (int __c);` в Linux точно не макрос.

Answer (score 3):

Позволю себе заметить, что такой функции - `int putchar(char)` - нет, есть [`int putchar(int)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/putchar).

В Open Watcom, по сути, так (я не буду писать здесь все эти модификаторы и прочее...):

```
int putchar(int c) { return fputc(c, stdout); }
```

Ну, а если вам хочется посмотреть на `fputc` - то добро пожаловать, мне ни голову, ни ноги ломать не хочется :)

```
_WCRTLINK int fputc( int c, FILE *fp )
{
    int flags;

    _ValidFile( fp, EOF );
    _AccessFile( fp );

    /*** Deal with stream orientation ***/
    ORIENT_STREAM(fp,EOF);

    if( !(fp->_flag & _WRITE) ) {
        __set_errno( EBADF );
        fp->_flag |= _SFERR;
        _ReleaseFile( fp );
        return( EOF );
    }
    if( _FP_BASE(fp) == NULL ) {
        __ioalloc( fp );
    }
    flags = _IONBF;
    if( c == '\n' ) {
        flags = _IONBF | _IOLBF;
#ifndef __UNIX__
        if( !(fp->_flag & _BINARY) ) {
            fp->_flag |= _DIRTY;
            *fp->_ptr = '\r';   /* '\n' -> '\r''\n' */
            fp->_ptr++;
            fp->_cnt++;
            if( fp->_cnt == fp->_bufsize ) {
                if( __flush( fp ) ) {
                    _ReleaseFile( fp );
                    return( EOF );
                }
            }
        }
#endif
    }
    fp->_flag |= _DIRTY;
    *fp->_ptr = c;
    fp->_ptr++;
    fp->_cnt++;
    if( (fp->_flag & flags) || (fp->_cnt == fp->_bufsize) ) {
        if( __flush( fp ) ) {
            _ReleaseFile( fp );
            return( EOF );
        }
    }
    _ReleaseFile( fp );
    return( (UCHAR_TYPE)c );
}
```